# Tagging video file metadata for media-players

Tags: video, metadata-editor

I wanted to ask if someone can provide me with a recommandation for tagging tools that I can use to tag my movies, series and documentaries, etc. (something like mp3tag but for video-files) so that build in media-player in TV's can read them appropriately.